# How to get value of dynamically generated input in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

Hello I am trying to get the value of dynamically generated input and then tie that to an onclick event handler that retrieves the value. I can't think of a way on how to do it. Here is the code:

```
h2 Labels
    each labelName in label
        h4 #{(JSON.stringify(labelName)).substr(1).slice(41, -1).replace(/['"]+/g, '')}
        form(action='/labelform', method='post', id='labelForm')
            input(type='hidden', value='#{(JSON.stringify(labelName.slice(41, -1))}', id='#{(JSON.stringify(labelName.slice(41, -1))}')
        button(type="button" onclick='enterStartTime()') Start Time 
        button(type="button" onclick='enterEndTime()') End Time
        br
```

Here is where the value of the dynamically generated input needs to go

```
label(for='startTime') start time
input(type='text', value=startTime, name='startTime', id='startTime', placeholder="00:01:00")
label(for='endTime') End Time
input(type='text', value=endTime, name='endTime', id='endTime', placeholder="00:02:15")
```

The value of the dynamically generated input can go into the input value of start time or end time. It doesn't matter

Comment: Can you explain "tie that to an onclick event handler that retrieves the value" further? It's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: simply put I want to create an onclick handler on the start time and end time button that retrieves the value of the input of 'labelForm' and make it as the value of another input.

Comment: This seems to be a javascript question rather than a pug question. Suggest changing the question tag to javascript.

Comment: Javascript tag added

Comment: "make it as the value of another input." Which input does this part refer to?

Comment: @kris I've updated the question to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the simplest way to do this is to have an event listener that triggers a function which passes the Id that is dynamically generated as a parameter.

```
h2 Labels
    each labelName in label
        h4 #{(JSON.stringify(labelName)).substr(1).slice(41, -1).replace(/['"]+/g, '')}
        form(action='/labelform', method='post', id='labelForm')
            input(type='hidden', onchange='addValue(#{(JSON.stringify(labelName.slice(41, -1))})', value='#{(JSON.stringify(labelName.slice(41, -1))}', id='#{(JSON.stringify(labelName.slice(41, -1))}')
        button(type="button" onclick='enterStartTime()') Start Time 
        button(type="button" onclick='enterEndTime()') End Time
        br
```

Where the value needs to go

```
label(for='startTime') start time
input(type='text', value=startTime, name='startTime', id='startTime', placeholder="00:01:00")
label(for='endTime') End Time
input(type='text', value=endTime, name='endTime', id='endTime', placeholder="00:02:15")
```

script function

```
    function addValue(labelName){
      document.getElementById('startTime').value = document.getElementById('labelName').value
}
```